# Наследование в PyQT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, наследование, pyqt

Мне нужно сделать несколько кнопок через `QPushButton`, с некоторыми общими настройками, поэтому я решил сделать класс `RegionButton` с наследованием от QPushButton. Он выглядит как-то так:

```
class RegionButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, region_name):
        super().__init__(region_name)
        self.rgn_name = region_name
        self.resize(60, 60)
        self.clicked.connect(MyWiget.show_text)
```

Но когда я попытался создать через него кнопку

```
reg = RegionButton("text_on_button")
reg.move(300, 400)
```

Код запустился, но кнопка не создалась(по крайней мере, ее не видно и тд). Что делать?

Comment: Вообще-то виджет без родителя - это окно. Добавьте после создание объекта `self.reg = RegionButton("text_on_button"); self.reg.move(reg)` - `self.reg.show()`. Обратите внимание, что я добавил `self` иначе переменная `reg` будет удалена сборщиком мусора. Если что-то не понятно - предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая и правильная идея создать отдельный класс, а я вам покажу вариант, как можно это сделать не создавая отдельный класс.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, geom_button):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Demo Room")
        self.geom_button = geom_button
        self.buttons = {}
        self.add_buttons()

    def add_buttons(self):
        for i, geom in enumerate(self.geom_button):
            self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
            self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.onLight(i))
            self.btn.setGeometry(*geom)
            path_image = "img/lightOff.png" 
            qss = 'border-image: url({})'.format(path_image)
            self.btn.setStyleSheet(qss)
            self.buttons[i] = (self.btn, 0) 
            
    def onLight(self, i):
        if self.buttons[i][1]:
            self.buttons[i][0].setStyleSheet('border-image: url({})'.format("img/lightOff.png"))
            self.buttons[i] = (self.buttons[i][0], 0)
        else:
            self.buttons[i][0].setStyleSheet('border-image: url({})'.format("img/lightOn.png"))
            self.buttons[i] = (self.buttons[i][0], 1)


geom_button = [
    (330,  70, 20, 30),(270, 110, 20, 20),(300, 110, 30, 30),(360, 110, 40, 40),(330, 150, 50, 50),
    (180, 190, 20, 30),(240, 190, 20, 20),(300, 190, 30, 30),(360, 190, 40, 40),(210, 230, 50, 50),
    (270, 230, 20, 30),(330, 230, 20, 20),(180, 270, 30, 30),(240, 270, 40, 40),(270, 270, 50, 50),
    (300, 270, 20, 30),(360, 270, 20, 20),(210, 310, 30, 30),(330, 310, 40, 40),(180, 350, 50, 50),
    (240, 350, 20, 30),(300, 350, 20, 20),(360, 350, 30, 30),(210, 390, 40, 40),(270, 390, 50, 50),
    (330, 390, 20, 30),(180, 430, 20, 20),(240, 430, 30, 30),(300, 430, 40, 40),(360, 430, 50, 50),
    (400, 230, 256, 256)
]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(geom_button)
    w.resize(800, 640)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]